# TCP connection deadlocks? ignores/dies?

Tags: .net, tcpclient

I cant reproduce this quickly but i know how to reproduce this.

When my client connects to the server and my client idles for a long time (it waits for the server to give it a msg as its subscribed to stuff) it is using `binaryread.ReadByte()` which is typecasted to an enum and used in a switch. After an unknown amount of time the server may send it a message BUT since the connection has been idle for a long time the server gets an exception and understands the client has been disconnected. The client (which is still on the switch doing ReadByte()) does NOT get an exception and just sits there. It doesnt even realize it is disconnected from the server.

Why doesn't it? How do i work around this? For now i use networkstream directly (which is the stream binaryreading is using) but i dont think this will be the correct solution.

How do i correctly solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have a timeout on the socket? (yes: it is a common problem that sockets can get silently broken - hence the need to use timeouts)

Comment: @MarcGravell: I do not. I guess i should. I didnt think i'd have to do anything by default......

Comment: @acidzombie24: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1011kecd.aspx